# Permit website reference from only certain url's

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

Suppose I have my own website say, **www.my-website.com** I want my website to be private such that it can be accessed from nowhere but could only be referenced from one website say, **www.some-other-website.com**. What changes should I make in .conf file of **www.my-website.com** so that I am able to do so?

Comment: Look at Deny and Allow.  You could deny all except if IP is the **some-other-website.com**'s IP.

Comment: We are using apache 2.4 in which deny and allow has been deprecated. However we have tried using Require all denied, Require host some-other-website.com but it doesn't seem to work